# Is it possible to put a badge on a UIToolbarItem?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to put a badge on a UIToolbarItem? I have four items on my bottom UIToolbar, but I need to put a badge on it (similar to push notification badge with a number) to notify the user of something. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean UITabBarItem, then there is a property badgeValue of type NSString. If you are talking about UIBarButtonItem you can use a customView and implement your own badge.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIBarButtonItem subclass, override drawRect.

To get the red badge, you can either [use an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041155/iphone-like-red-badge-notification-in-a-wpf-project) or [do the drawing yourself](http://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell).

Comment: The last example is drawing badges for table cells, not exactly what you're looking for, but will get you going.